# Difference between border and border-width attributes in CSS styling

Tags: html, css

What is the difference between the CSS styles below?

```
border: 5px;
```

vs

```
border-width: 5px;
```

Comment: `border` is shorthand for `border-width`, `border-style` and `border-color`

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use :

```
border: 5px;
```

Then you have to use 3 shorthand property with it:

```
border-width
border-style (required)
border-color
```

When you use the only width it will not work, you have to also write border-style, and If you write the only style of Border then it works with default width and default color as the text color.

And When you use:

```
border-width: 5px;
```

It will assign border-width shorthand CSS property and sets the widths of all four sides of an element's border.

Comment: The `border` property will work fine without all three attributes, as per the MDN docs. As long as the order is preserved, `5px`, `5px solid`, and `solid black` are all valid values: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border

Comment: But it will not work without  `border-style`, as per [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border.asp).

Comment: Ah yes, you're right! MDN actually shows that as well, I just missed it.

Comment: @NikolasStevenson-Molnar no need any particular order `solid 2px` or `black 2px solid` or `black solid 2px` will work